# CMS Solutions for Existing MVC4 Project

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I have an MVC4 project, there is a public facing site, and a secured/authenticated site.

The public facing site is semi-dynamically created. An xml file defines tabs and pages, and the site creates the navigation and loads the pages accordingly.

[image]

The HTML pages that are being loaded are using the Bootstrap framework. The content looks something like(notice the Bootstrap class attributes):

[image]

My goal here is to create/provide a content management system, so these HTML pages can be maintained by our Communications department(very minimal html knowledge).  I was hoping to integrate an existing CMS to manage these pages.
Or at very minimum, I was going to crate my OWN CMS, and use a prebuilt WYSIWYG editor to edit content.

So my actual question is:

a) Does anyone have experience with a simple .NET CMS solution that can be easily integrated into an existing MVC project and that works with Bootstrap framework?

b) Does anyone know of any WYSIWYG editors that work with, or can be easily customized to work with the Bootstrap framework?

***The only CMS I've really come across wth DNN and Orchard, but both seem to be a little overkill for what I actually need, plus I don't think they will play well with Bootstrap.*

Answer (score 0):

A CMS, by it's nature is going to be specific to the application, so no, there aren't any drop-in CMS applications that can just magically provide editing capabilities for your entities.

DNN, Orchard, etc. are likely overkill, but that's because they are not really content management systems. They are full applications that just happen to deal with creating websites. You can use them as a CMS, but then you also need to utilize their website code as well in order to take advantage of the CMS features. In other words, you build your application from the ground up on the back of DNN, Orchard, etc. You don't just shoe-horn it in at the last moment.

Long and short, you need to do the work yourself. There's no plug-n-play solution to something like this. That said, a CMS is an incredibly simple thing to build. It's just CRUD, so you create a controller for each entity and then add actions and views to create, view, update and delete those entities.